# Marketing Cloud Connect - Data Sources -How to resolve "sync prerequisites" on Synchronize entity in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sync

I am new to salesƒroce integration. I am trying to connect my custom/delivered objects from Service cloud to Marketing cloud using Marketing cloud connect. I have successfully downloaded and configured from below link.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_marketing_cloud_connect.htm&type=5

Now, I am trying to synchronize my custom/delivered object in marketing cloud but it is not allowing me to do so.
I am getting this message and I am not sure how and where to do this step.

[image]

Please let me know if anyone has any idea.

I really appreciate your time and reply.

Comment: The message is pretty clear [unless I am missing something] - you have to first synchronize the objects listed before you can synchronize your custom object. This would be based on the existing data relationships you've established between the objects in Salesforce. You may find that after synchronizing just a portion of the objects listed the object becomes available, so keep an eye on that to see if it becomes available.

Comment: Try to synchronize the objects that are in the error popup and then try to sync your custom objects. Make sure you give admin privileges to the API user so that it can able to access the custom objects

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the reply. I understand the message but I am not sure how to synchronize User/Lead and Contact? That is my issue here.

Comment: Could you please give me some information on how to synchronize those then that would be a great help.

Comment: Use the search bar (seen in the screenshot you provided) and search for the object names. You should see each one since those are standard objects.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Finally, I figured this out and successfully synchronized my custom objects.

Comment: Good to hear. I've added as an official answer, if you want to give this an official resolved status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message in your screenshot is descriptive of the issue. You have to first synchronize the objects listed before you can synchronize your custom object. This would be based on the existing data relationships you've established between the objects in Salesforce. You may find that after synchronizing just a portion of the objects listed the object becomes available (in particular the 'User' object seems to enable most), so keep an eye on that to see if it becomes available.

If you're having trouble finding those prerequisite objects, use the search bar (seen in the screenshot you provided) and search for the object names. You should see each one since those are standard objects.